# Lista de dias entre 2 fechas PHP

Tags: php

se que existen miles de post en base a calcular días entre dos fechas, pero nunca encontré lo que buscaba.
Necesito que al poner 2 fechas (cada una con su variable), me tire la lista de días que hay en el medio pero no la cantidad de días.
Por ej:
Si elijo 13/03/2019 y 20/03/2019 me haga una lista de los días entre ese rango.
Miércoles 13
Jueves 14
Viernes 15 y así sucesivamente hasta la fecha final indicada.
Espero que se entienda... gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask]; edita y muéstranos que llevas?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este ejemplo espero te sirva: http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/obtener-todas-las-fechas-entre-dos-fechas-872205/

Este es el código

```php
   <?php
    $fecha1 = "2018-12-29";
    $fecha2 = "2019-01-12";

    for($i=$fecha1;$i<=$fecha2;$i = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i ."+ 1 days")))
    {
        echo dia_semana($i). "<br />";
    }


    function dia_semana($fecha)
    {
        $dia = date("d", strtotime($fecha));

        $dias = array('', 'LUNES', 'MARTES', 'MIERCOLES', 'JUEVES', 'VIERNES', 'SÁBADO', 'DOMINGO');
        $dia_semana = $dias[date('N', strtotime($fecha))];
        echo $dia_semana.' '.$dia;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por responder, es practicamente lo que necesito, solo que ahora tengo que ver como agrego el nombre del dia :D , pero gracias igual.

Comment: Añadí una función extra a la respuesta, con eso se obtiene el nombre del día

Comment: Eres el mejor LEJOS!!! Muchas gracias me salvaste la vida :D

Comment: @chunilp es importante que leas el [tour]. Ademas de las gracias, las respuestas que contestan la pregunta deben aceptarse.

Comment: listo, perdon es q es la primera vez q publico en un foro pero creo q ahi esta :D

Comment: Que bueno que te haya servido :-). PD: Soy una chica.

Comment: Te juro q todo el tiempo pensé (estoy seguro q es una chica pero dude porq me parecio raro que el el codigo no hayas puesto como comentario algún corazoncito jajaja). Gracias por tu ayuda chica.